# Unable to define Active Record Associations properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have got the following models,

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
  belongs_to :country
end

class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country

  has_many :cities
end

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :states
  has_many :cities, :through => :state
end
```

This is my schema.rb,

```
create_table "cities", :force => true do |t| 
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "state_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end 

create_table "countries", :force => true do |t| 
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end 

create_table "states", :force => true do |t| 
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "country_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

This is my seed data,

```
country_in = Country.create(name: 'India')

state_ap = country_in.states.create(name: 'Andhra Pradesh')
state_mh = country_in.states.create(name: 'Maharashtra')

city_hyd = state_ap.cities.create(name: 'Hyderabad')
state_ap.cities.create([{name: 'Tirupathi'}, {name: 'Visakhapatnam'}])
state_mh.cities.create([{name: 'Mumbai'}, {name: 'Pune'}, {name: 'Thane'}])
```

**Problem**

When I try to find all cities under "India" using

`country_in.cities`

I get this error : `ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :state in model Country`

When I try to find which country the city "Hyderabad" is, using

`city_hyd.country` , I get `nil`

Why are the links between cities and countries not present?

Are my associations wrong is there something else I missed out on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing link here is the following (see the ["Rails Guides for Associations"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association)):

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :states
  has_many :cities, :through => :states
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
  def country
    state ? state.country : nil
  end
end
```

My changes were the following:

- `has_many :through` needs the plural form, not the singular.
- If you use `belongs_to` in `City`, there needs to be a `state_id` defined in the table (which would be redundant). So I have replaced it through a getter method. A corresponding setter method is not possible.

I hope that now works for you.